# Alternative for Garbage/Default value along the lines of nullptr - C++

Tags: c++

I had a question in which I had to create an integer array of say, 10 elements. Only some of the elements were edited and not in a specific order. For example, the program might only work with the elements at index 3, 0, 4, 7 and the value stored could be any integer (all possible values of int). Finally, I had to take the maximum of all the elements which were modified by the program and display it.

To identify which elements were modified, this was my approach: I declared the array a long int array instead of the required int and initialised all the elements with values beyond int, suppose a `const long int max = -214748300`. This way if the value of the element in the array matched `max`, I would know that they had not modified.

What I want to know is that is there any way for doing this without modifying the data type? I'm searching for any standard library implementation similar to `nullptr` for pointers, but which works on `int` or `char` datatypes. I'm interested mainly in C++ implementations, but implementations in other languages are welcome too.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Do not tag a question for one with the other.

Comment: A `long` isn't always wider than an `int`. They are typically the same width on 32-bit operating systems (and are also the same width on 64-bit Windows). Two approaches spring to mind: (1) use a `struct` to hold the value and a "modified" status; (2) use an auxiliary array of flags to "modified" status of each index in the main array. The second approach can be made more space-efficient with a bit of clever code, as it only needs one bit per element of the main array.

Comment: The most well-known language with a "value not present"  is of course SQL with its `NULL`. It's so prevalent there that `non-NULL` is the adaptation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that technically speaking you want "int or undefined" which is what types like [boost::optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html) (which may get [standartized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/optional)) are for.

But of course those types are not zero-cost and have a slight overhead.

Otherwise you can bundle flags next to the value by using `std::pair<bool,int>` or have two seperate collections like `std::vector<bool> changed;`(insert mandatory `vector<bool>` disclaimer) and `std::vector<int> values;`. Both of which obviously require you to manage the semantic connection between the two manually.

If you're already doing that and having the extra bool is too burdensome you can also use a bitfield like:

```
struct optional_uint
{
  unsigned int is_unset :1;
  unsigned int value    :31;
};
```

Just requires you to initialize them with `is_unset` set to 1.

Which solution is best for you, really depends on your requirements.

Comment: That wouldn't work with "all possible values of int" though.

Comment: yes, I'd edit my comment to say I was referring to the bitfield struct, but the 5 minute editing window has expired now.